# index scan instead of index seek on columns with OR operator

Tags: sql-server, performance-tuning

I am trying to tune following query

```
select
-
-
-
FROM
Table1.Column1 = 'I'
and
(
Table1.column2 in (1234) 
OR  
Table2.column2 in (1234)
)
```

I am trying to improve query execution time but it takes around 1300ms to finish. However, if I exclude one of the column with OR operator then it only takes 20ms.

I do have non-clustered index on both columns but for some reason it does index scan(non-clustered) on table2.column2 table which scan all 1.4 million records.

What would be the best option to improve query to convert index scan into index seek on columns used with OR operator. I am trying to bring total execution time less than 100ms.

Comment: [How To Get Answers To SQL Server Performance Questions](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/how-to-get-answers-to-sql-server-performance-questions/)

Comment: There is no smoking gun when it comes to query tuning; you haven't mentioned what DBMS or version you are using and that makes a big difference as their optimizers handle queries very differently sometimes. Also you have table1 and table2, are they joined or are you doing subqueries? It's hard to help without more info.

Comment: It's a SQL server 2019

Comment: That is not even a valid query...

Answer (score 1):

I might have figured out. I re-wrote query using UNION operator instead of OR operator and it brought down total execution time rom 1300ms to 60ms.

```
Select * from (
select
-
-
-
FROM
Table1.Column1 = 'I'
and
Table1.column2 in (1234) 
UNION
select
-
-
-
FROM
Table1.Column1 = 'I'
and
Table2.column2 in (1234)
) q
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without the data, however like you suggest the UNION can optimize it. But instead of UNION, when you know the data is unique, you might be able to optimize it more by using an UNION ALL instead of UNION.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1387/union-vs-union-all-in-sql-server/